# oracle left outer joins not showing null values but displays same value

Tags: oracle

Problem is in left outer join, when there are no rows in right side table then it does not display `null` values, it displays previous values....

Like this....

1 st Table contains

```
PGMTX_CODE    PGMTX_MARKS    PGMTX_TOTQSTN
-------------------------------------------
EE            1              5

EE            2              5

EE            3              0

EE            4              0
```

2 nd Table contains

```
PGMTX_CODE    PGMTX_MARKS    PGMTX_ACTUSEDQST
-------------------------------------------
EE            1              5
```

So I want result like...

```
PGMTX_MARKS    PGMTX_TOTQSTN     PGMTX_ACTUSEDQST
--------------------------------------------------
1              5                 5

2              5                 blank

3              0                 blank

4              0                 blank
```

I use query like this...

```
SELECT m.PGMTX_MARKS, 
       m.PGMTX_TOTQSTN, 
       tlm.PGMTX_ACTUSEDQST, 
  from PAPERGEN_MTL_OEX m 
       left OUTER JOIN  PAPERGEN_TLMTL_OEX tlm 
         ON m.PGMTX_CODE=tlm.PGMTX_CODE
 where m.PGMTX_CODE='EE' 
 order by m.PGMTX_MARKS
```

But I got result like

```
PGMTX_MARKS    PGMTX_TOTQSTN     PGMTX_ACTUSEDQST
--------------------------------------------------
1              5                 5

2              5                 5

3              0                 5

4              0                 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Your join condition is wrong, should be

```
ON m.PGMTX_CODE=tlm.PGMTX_CODE AND m.PGMTX_MARKS = tlm.PGMTX_MARKS
```

Comment: when I give marks condition as u say then it returns only one row.
But I want all rows from left table which matches only PGMTX_CODE

Comment: I can only add that in some cases we need to think simple. This problem is like: we have new foreign student and we must assign him to class. We cannot assign him only to the given semester, but we need also assign him to specific specific specialization.

Comment: But it not satisfy the requirement. if I want to achieve that result so how can I achieve that result please suggest me....

Comment: I bet you appended `AND m.PGMTX_MARKS = tlm.PGMTX_MARKS` to the `where` clause instead of the `join` clause.

Comment: No I appended it to join clause like this......
SELECT  m.PGMTX_MARKS, m.PGMTX_TOTQSTN, tlm.PGMTX_ACTUSEDQST
from PAPERGEN_MTL_OEX m LEFT OUTER JOIN PAPERGEN_TLMTL_OEX tlm ON m.PGMTX_CODE=tlm.PGMTX_CODE 
and  m.PGMTX_MARKS=tlm.PGMTX_MARKS where m.PGMTX_CODE='EE' order by m.PGMTX_MARKS
and I fire this in toad....

Comment: Check your tables again. yamny posted a link to sqlfiddle, where you can see that the join condition works as expected. Something else must be wrong.